# Pasting images from clipboard with Chrome

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor, images

It seems to be with the latest Chrome update (35.0.1916.114) I no longer am able to copy/paste pictures into the "Add Image" dialog box when creating an answer. However, I can still paste pictures if i go directly to the Imgur website and use their web upload dialog box. Is this an intended change? It is a super useful feature.

I'm on a Mac running 10.9.3. (also didn't work with 10.9.2)

As you can see in the screen shot, there is no "or paste" option listed.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Related: [Why is paste/drag-and-drop of images not available on some browsers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188656/168244)

Comment: New Question I just posted: [Pasting images from the clipboard doesn't seem to work anymore on Chrome for Linux](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411266/4561887)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `Clipboard` interface name has been changed to `DataTransfer`, without any backwards compatibility:

http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?view=revision&revision=168494

Unfortunately, that broke our feature detection and disabling "paste" on Chrome in the process.

The fix isn't easy because though other browsers implement this interface, the implementation vary (if they work at all) and we would end up claiming paste support on browsers where paste isn't supported.

We are looking into a solution, but have no timeframe.

---

This is now fixed, though we don't advertise the fact on the popup. WebKit only, ATM.

Comment: Even if you can't sniff to show the that the "paste" option is available on the dialog, could you at least listen to the `DataTransfer` signals? I find it's much easier to answer questions about plots when it's super easy to copy/paste results. It's killing my productivity.

Comment: @MrFlick - changing the implementation and making sure it works correctly (and advertises correctly) on different platforms and browsers takes time.

Comment: In the mean time, why not just add the text "where available" to the message (i.e. "or paste or drag-and-drop where available"). This way users who do not have that functionality available will be aware that it probably wont work (they are probably used to nothing working if they are using an old browser). Moreover, this will allow just about everyone else to go on using the existing feature. Just as a temporary solution while an updated feature detection process is implemented.