# Copy and paste image into editor

Tags: feature-request

It was said [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258184/have-lost-an-ability-to-paste-images-into-posts) that there was a bug and it is now fixed that you couldn't paste an image from clipboard.

However, that was posted **2 years ago** and I think it would be awesome if I didn't have to save files into my PC. So, can we get that feature back?

Answer (score 3):

Copy/Paste Just Works™

> [This is now fixed, though we don't advertise the fact on the popup. WebKit only, ATM.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255907/578411)

and I verified [Oded's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded) claim on my Chrome setup version Versie 52.0.2743.116 m on Windows 10. See below the result

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for me and I'm using the latest version of Chrome

Comment: Are you on windows?

Comment: Yes, Windows 10

Comment: Works for me too, latest Chrome on Windows 7. @AbAppletic Are you trying to right click to paste, or just `ctrl v`?