# Pasting images from the clipboard doesn't seem to work anymore on Chrome for Linux

Tags: support, images

I can't paste images into Stack Overflow anymore. Does anyone else have this problem?

I'm on Chrome Version 93.0.4577.63 (Official Build) (64-bit) in Linux [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29).

The snipping tools I tried are Shutter and Screenshot. I get the same behavior on two computers, each running Chrome (and logged into my Chrome account, with my Chrome plugins). One computer is Ubuntu 18.04, and the other is [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)).

Note: there are a bunch of "duplicates" of this question, but since they are old, they no longer apply in the event that this is a new bug or newly-introduced regression.

See comments below. The problem seems to exist in the Chrome browser only...

### See also:

1. [I posted this question here too] https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361992/pasting-images-from-the-clipboard-into-a-stack-exchange-site-stack-overflow-as?noredirect=1#comment2341105_1361992

Comment: I just used the Windows snippet tool (Win + Ctrl + s) and pasted directly into the Answer box and it got me [this part of your Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9KeU.png). It works with Opera.

Comment: @Scratte, I wonder if it's a Chrome plugin problem or Chrome bug...

Comment: You could install a few other browsers to find out if it's the browser, no?

Comment: I just checked in FireFox. It works. It's the browser...

Comment: I still get the problem in Chrome's incognito mode too, which seems to imply the problem is *not* my Chrome plugins?

Comment: The problem also exists in Chrome's "Guest" mode. So, again, it seems to not be my plugins, but the browser itself. Anyone else experiencing this in Chrome on any other OSs?

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome 92.0.4515.159 (and 93.0.4577.63, after updating) on Win10.  I was just able to paste into the answer box on this question.

Comment: @RyanM, thanks. I wonder if anyone else on Ubuntu can verify if this is an Ubuntu-specific issue.

Comment: No problems on [Ubuntu MATE 20.04 (Focal Fossa)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) with Firefox 91.0.2.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, can you try on Ubuntu with my version of Chrome?

Comment: @Gabriel Staples: That would have to be in a sandbox of some kind (separate hardware or a VM). Can you recommend something?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, try [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). It's high-quality, and no-cost. You can install Ubuntu 20.04 into it.

Comment: @Gabriel Staples: I will give it a try (but it will take some time).

Comment: Works fine on Chrome 93.0.4577.63, for Mac. Issue seems pretty localized.

Comment: No repro in Chromium 92.0.4515.159 (Official Build) (64-bit), Chrome 93.0.4577.63 (Official Build) (64-bit), or Firefox 91.0.2 (64-bit) on Mint 20.2 (Based on Ubuntu 20.04.3).

Comment: Also not reproducible on Chromium 93.0.4577.63 for Arch Linux.

Comment: To further confuse me, pasting images works fine from my work's stack enterprise stack overflow system on the same computer and in the same Chrome browser at https://company_name.stackenterprise.co/.

Comment: I also have this problem, it's not StackExchange related, because the same thing also doesn't work for me on other sites. It still worked last week.
I am running 92.0.4515.159 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got a temporary solution for this problem from the Chromium team:

1. Go to **chrome://flags/#use-ozone-platform** in your browser.
2. For the "Use ozone" setting, select "Disabled", as shown here:
   [image]

I assume that now that this problem is known, they will eventually fix it so that changing this setting won't be necessary anymore.

Bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1246811

EDIT (2021-11-30): As of Chrome version 96.0.4664.45 this works again without any extra settings, so if you are having this problem on an older version you just need to update.

Comment: Where did you get this solution? Is there a bug report or discussion you can link to?

Comment: Added the link to the answer

Comment: I am using latest chrome Version 94.0.4606.61 (Official Build) (64-bit) and I still need this work around. thank you!

Comment: I used this fix in the past and it worked but today I noticed I can't paste again and this flag is not available anymore in Chrome so I can't switch it off in Chrome version 95.0.4638.54

Comment: The same thing happened for me, but now that I have 96.0.4664.45, this works again without any extra settings